# Dispatching a thunk from a middleware results in an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-middleware

I have a thunk defined in my `actions.js` file:

```
export const myThunk = (param1, param2, param3) => {
   return dispatch => {
      dispatch({type: types.myThunkType})
      fetch(`https://mockurl.com?param1=${param1}&param2=${param2}&param3=${param3}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
         dispatch({type: types.everythingsAllRight, payload: data.results})
      })
   }
}
```

When I dispatch this from a React component, everything works like a charm. In my `component.js` we have something like this:

```
import myThunk from './actions/actions.js'
const dispatch = useDispatch()

return (
   <button onClick={() => {dispatch(myThunk(props.param1, props.param2, props.param3)}>
)
```

But when I try to use this same thunk from a middleware, like this:

```
   store.dispatch(anPlainObjectActionDefinedInActionsJsToo(param1, param2, false))
   .then(() => { 
      store.dispatch({
         type: types.anotherImportantActionType,
         payload: {
            thisData: someData,
            thatData: someOtherData
         }
      })
   })
   .then(store.dispatch(myThunk(param1, param2, param3)))
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

The error is hiting the middleware that deals with action types `myThunkType`:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/Store/middleware/middlewareThatDealsWithMyThunkTupeActionType.js:9
   6 | }
   7 | if (action.type !== types.myThunkType &&
   8 |    action.type !== types.anotherType) {
>  9 |    return next(action)
     | ^  10 | }
  11 |
```

As it can't "return next action". Any hints of what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Inspecting in debug, I found that the dispatched thunk appears like that when it hits the middleware: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL215.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function to your `.then` but not immediately call it like you currently do. Also, change your middleware to use [currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/) to pass dispatch and create a closure. Rewrite the final `then` block to

```
.then(() => {
store.dispatch(myThunk(param1, param2, param3))
})
```

You can read more about custom redux middleware and currying [here](https://redux.js.org/faq/design-decisions#why-does-the-middleware-signature-use-currying)

Comment: You're right that I need to do it but, unfortunately, I'm getting the same error whatsoever.

Comment: try and write it in this syntax  .then(() => {
myThunk(param1, param2, param3)(store.dispatch)
})

Comment: It worked! Can you point out any material to read about this kind of syntax? I can't understand why it worked!

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to materials that explain how redux works with custom middleware. Please mark the answer as accepted if this helps.